# RTRIM in a sql statement in wordpress

Tags: sql, mysql

I'm trying to check a filename in a sql statement, that I'm using in PHP, in a wordpress template I'm building.

Bascially I'm trying to use `LTRIM` to only bring back images that have `_a` on the end.

eg I have a bunch of images in a series of folders

- `clientone_a.jpg`
- `clienttwo_b.jpg`
- ...etc...

this is what Im using at the moment but it doesnt work;

```
$query = "
    SELECT F.field_value, P.alttext, P.filename, P.description, p.galleryid, 
        G.path 
    FROM wp_nggcf_field_values F, 
        wp_ngg_pictures P, 
        wp_ngg_gallery G 
    WHERE F.fid=1 
        AND (F.field_value='".$data."') 
        AND F.pid = P.PID 
        AND P.galleryid = G.gid 
        AND LTRIM(P.filename,'_') = '_a.jpg'
";

$caseStudiesResults = $wpdb->get_results($query);
```

It's just the last `LTRIM(P.filename,'_') = '_a.jpg'` that is the problem, without that it bring back all the images, and I'm after bringing back the `_a` one only.

Any ideas on where I'm going wrong ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're using the wrong function.  [`LTRIM()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_ltrim) simply removes leading spaces.  What you're looking for is [`SUBSTRING_INDEX()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index)

```
AND SUBSTRING_INDEX(P.filename, '_', -1) = 'a.jpg'
```

The `-1` tells it to return everything to the right of the final delimiter (`-2` would be everything to the right of the 2nd to last delimiter, `1` would be everything to the left of the first, etc)...

**Edit:** As far as testing it, you can test string functions by doing this:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX('test_a.jpg', '_', -1) = 'a.jpg'
```

Run that, and see if it works (it did for me).  By putting static values, you can try it out without needing to run the whole big query...

Comment: That's just what I was looking for ! Thanks everything is great now.

Answer (score 1):

alternative to `substring_index`

```
select substring('clientone_a.jpg', -6)='_a.jpg';
```

Comment: Given the static nature of the comparison (`_a.jpg`), that would work quite well (I'm not sure of the performance difference between the functions, but I'm sure it's not too large).  +1 to you as well...